# quasi nested conditions in bash is failing, because of elif syntax error

Tags: bash, syntax

I have code that performs some conditionals in bash:

```
firstchar=$(head -c 1 /tmp/project.json)
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then;
  echo "Hooray! nothing found"

elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then                    
  #check single project
  if [[ $firstchar == "{" ]]; then         
    echo "SINGLE PROJECT"
  elif [[ $firstchar == "[" ]]; then
    echo "MULTIPROJECT"
  else
    echo "didnot get a single or multiproject"
  fi

elif [ $? -eq 2 ] then;
  echo "An error occurred, please contact me"

elif [ $? -eq 3 ] then;
  echo "lah"

else
  echo "Something else occurred on file"
fi
```

why would it fail to execute mentioning: `7: syntax error near unexpected token elif'`

Thanks

Comment: I recommend [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for stuff like this

Comment: i am no expert on bash script, but i see inconsistency in your code

Comment: Have your ran it through `shellcheck`: e.g. `shellcheck my_script`?

Comment: Note too that the value of `$?` changes with each test, to reflect the outcome of the test. It would be better to use `case ... esac` here, to only evaluate `$?` once, or possibly assign it to a separate variable. But then again, why check for other values than zero and non-zero? Does your `head` utility document 2 and 3 as specific exit statuses?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `if [ $? -eq 0 ] then;`

This should be `if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then`

You  got some of these right, but a number wrong.

The reason it didn't like the `elif` is because it was part of the tests on the `if`, since there had not been a statement starting `then`.

Comment: Also, the value of `$?` will change throughout the `if` statement, as each test resets it. Try e.g. `if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo 1; elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo 2; fi`.

Comment: And run through `shellcheck` I see other problems.